# python, list everything between two tags

Tags: python, string, tags

I'm looking for the shortest neatest way to code the folloing.

say I have a string containing: `'the f<ox jumpe>d over the l<azy> dog <and the >fence'`

Using < as the opening tag and > as the closing tag, I would like to save everything inbetween into a list.

if saved into list1, list1 would equal ['ox jumpe', 'azy', 'and the ']

Who knows of a nice, neat **SHORT** way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can there be nesting? e.g. <ox <j>umpe>

Comment: ...or escaping? eg. `'one is g<reater tha>n (\>) zero'`

Comment: Just in case. If you are even thinking about parsing html, **DON'T** use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: mm good questions, lets make it so if you had <ox <j>umpe> the result would store ['ox <j>umpe', 'j'] ... and no escsping

Comment: @Rhys: I have no idea, sorry, but don't really. Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 dispute the humor, it is a good rule of thumb. The only case where this **might** be a good idea is for a small **limited and known** html input.

Comment: lol ok i'll stay away from it then ... thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions should do the trick here:

```
import re

text = 'the f<ox jumpe>d over the l<azy> dog <and the >fence'
list = re.findall('.*?\<(.*?)\>.*?', text)

print list
```

**Edit:**

You can read more about regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Mainly, what the regex from above does is:

.*? - non greedy match of all the characters until next wanted char

\< - matches the < char

(.*?) - non greedy match of all the characters until next wanted char, capture and returns them

Comment: I've seen this findall before, I've always been scared away by '.*?\<(.*?)\>.*?' this kind of stuff, now that i see in context how to use it ... it makes sence ... but why does one need to incude all the symbol characters?

Very helpful though, thanks a tone!

Comment: You are welcome - you can show your gratitude with an upvote and accept - I edited the response to include some explanations.

Comment: Just `list = re.findall('<(.*?)>', text)` gives the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every "<" and every ">" indicate the start or end of a tag e.g. you cant have `<hi<there>`:

```
x="<a><bb><ccc>"
>>> starts=(i for i,c in enumerate(x) if c=="<")
>>> ends=(i for i,c in enumerate(x) if c==">")
>>> ans=[x[i+1:j] for i,j in zip(starts,ends)]
>>> ans
['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
```

use izip if it is a large xml file to save memory (Although x[i+1:j] would need to be changed as you wouldn't want the whole file as a string).